# Order is complete send order confirmation email only to "admin email address" not to customer magento 2.4.0

Tags: email, sales, magento2.4.0

**Email Confirmation**

When order is "complete" send order confirmation email only to "admin email address"
not to customer
for every payment method.

Advance Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

This is Magento code

```php
/**
             * we only want to send to customer about new order when there is no redirect to third party
             */
            if (!$redirectUrl && $order->getCanSendNewEmailFlag()) {
                try {
                    $this->orderSender->send($order);
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->_logger->critical($e);
                }
            }
```

From this logic, you can set the `CanSendNewEmailFlag` to `false`, it will no longer send order emails.

Here is an example from Paypal
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/aaeadff2f3130f2ddf14018cb64ca259799d1a1c/app/code/Magento/Paypal/Model/Payflowlink.php#L250